# OpenCart adding "informational" field in admin

Tags: admin, field, opencart

I am looking for a way to add a field in the admin for my information pages. I just need it in the admin and not looking to show any data from the field on front end.

To explain better the list page for my information pages is set up like this:

```
Information Title | Sort Order | Action
```

I want to add an identifying blurb that will display before the title in admin so at a glance I can look and see which store (I'm running multi-store) that info page is assigned to. I'm guessing the actual field would need to be added to the add/edit form and then somehow told to display that field input on the list page.

I do have vQmod installed and have looked at the documentation but I just can't wrap my head around this.

I would REALLY appreciate any help on this.

Here's the code from information.php.

```
<?php
class ModelCatalogInformation extends Model {
    public function getInformation($information_id) {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "information i LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "information_description id ON (i.information_id = id.information_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "information_to_store i2s ON (i.information_id = i2s.information_id) WHERE i.information_id = '" . (int)$information_id . "' AND id.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' AND i2s.store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "' AND i.status = '1'");

    //return $query->row;
  $r = $query->row;
$r['title'] = preg_replace('/ ## .+/','',$r['title']);
return $r;
    }

    public function getInformations() {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "information i LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "information_description id ON (i.information_id = id.information_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "information_to_store i2s ON (i.information_id = i2s.information_id) WHERE id.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' AND i2s.store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "' AND i.status = '1' ORDER BY i.sort_order, LCASE(id.title) ASC");

        //return $query->rows;
    $result = $query->rows;

foreach ($result as $key => $r){
    $result[$key] = preg_replace('/ ## .+/','',$r['title']);
}

return $result;
    }

    public function getInformationLayoutId($information_id) {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "information_to_layout WHERE information_id = '" . (int)$information_id . "' AND store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "'");

        if ($query->num_rows) {
            return $query->row['layout_id'];
        } else {
            return $this->config->get('config_layout_information');
        }
    }   
}
?>
```

When you mentioned checking the vQmod cache it dawned on me that I'm using a mod that hides info pages from the menu by using -1 sort order. Here's the information.php from the cache folder.

```
<?php
class ModelCatalogInformation extends Model {
    public function getInformation($information_id) {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "information i LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "information_description id ON (i.information_id = id.information_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "information_to_store i2s ON (i.information_id = i2s.information_id) WHERE i.information_id = '" . (int)$information_id . "' AND id.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' AND i2s.store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "' AND i.status = '1'");

    return $query->row;
    }

    public function getInformations() {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "information i LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "information_description id ON (i.information_id = id.information_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "information_to_store i2s ON (i.information_id = i2s.information_id) WHERE id.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' AND i2s.store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "' AND i.status = '1' AND i.sort_order <> '-1' ORDER BY i.sort_order, LCASE(id.title) ASC");

        return $query->rows;
    }

    public function getInformationLayoutId($information_id) {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "information_to_layout WHERE information_id = '" . (int)$information_id . "' AND store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "'");

        if ($query->num_rows) {
            return $query->row['layout_id'];
        } else {
            return $this->config->get('config_layout_information');
        }
    }   
}
?>
```

Comment: `ETA` means `Estimated Time of Arrival`, You sure You wanted to use it with OpenCart's version? :-)

Comment: Check whether vqmod is modifying information.php by looking in vqcache folder. If yes, open it and see what changes are applied. Then post here.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your purpose correctly, I have an easier solution for you.
Add your description in the Title field , use some unique token to indicate the beginning of this description, it will not render in the front end, Example:
I use `##` here as token.

*My Title ## This page is for Store 1*

then edit `catalog/model/catalog/information`, in function `getInformation()` find line:

```php
return $query->row;
```

replace with:

```php
//return $query->row;
$r = $query->row;
$r['title'] = preg_replace('/ ## .+/','',$r['title']);
return $r;
```

in function `getInformations()` find line:

```php
return $query->rows;
```

replace with:

```php
//return $query->rows;

$result = $query->rows;

foreach ($result as $key => $r){
    $result[$key] = preg_replace('/ ## .+/','',$r['title']);
}

return $result;
```

You're done.

Comment: Just gave this a try and got an error on front end.

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PUBLIC in /home4/dreamse3/public_html/cart/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-catalog_model_catalog_information.php on line 11

Comment: Pretty nice solution. Though not perfect, but with just a very little work needed to be done. +1

Comment: @flightoffancy Maybe You edited something wrongly then... I do not see any problem here in the answer...

Comment: Before i posted my answer, i tested the code on oc1.5.5.1. No errors.

Comment: @shadyyx what was wrong with passing value by reference in the foreach loop? Thanks.

Comment: I'll give it another shot when I get home this evening. Do I need to have the ## token and appended text in place before making the changes to the information.php file?

Comment: @flightoffancy no, you do not need to have it. There will be no match found and nothing will be replaced. That's all.

Comment: @B-and-P 1. It's archaic. 2. PHP 5 uses references automatically. **3. It's much quicker to access directly a value via index key than passing by reference.** 4. And it's cleaner... :-)

Comment: Just got around to trying this again and it DOES work in the information module side box, not so much in the footer. In the footer it's only displaying the first letter of the information page title.

Comment: @flightoffancy: makes no sense... post your exact code and let us see.

Comment: @flightoffancy: why did you post default information.php code? We need to see YOUR code. **Show what you have done.**

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly for the sidebox Info display, however if you are using a theme with columns and pulling in the Info links to display there, it only pulls in the first letter of each link title.

Here is the code for the footer. I am using the identical setup as flightoffancy in same cart version:

This is from catalog/controller/common/footer:

```
    $this->load->model('catalog/information');

    $this->data['informations'] = array();

    foreach ($this->model_catalog_information->getInformations() as $result) {
        if ($result['bottom']) {
            $this->data['informations'][] = array(
                'title' => $result['title'],
                'href'  => $this->url->link('information/information', 'information_id=' . $result['information_id'])
            );
        }
    }

    $this->data['contact'] = $this->url->link('information/contact');
    $this->data['return'] = $this->url->link('account/return/insert', '', 'SSL');
    $this->data['sitemap'] = $this->url->link('information/sitemap');
    $this->data['manufacturer'] = $this->url->link('product/manufacturer');
    $this->data['voucher'] = $this->url->link('account/voucher', '', 'SSL');
    $this->data['affiliate'] = $this->url->link('affiliate/account', '', 'SSL');
    $this->data['special'] = $this->url->link('product/special');
    $this->data['account'] = $this->url->link('account/account', '', 'SSL');
    $this->data['order'] = $this->url->link('account/order', '', 'SSL');
    $this->data['wishlist'] = $this->url->link('account/wishlist', '', 'SSL');
    $this->data['newsletter'] = $this->url->link('account/newsletter', '', 'SSL');
```

Comment: It cannot happen as you describe it because it is **the same function** you are calling from the model. It **cannot** return a letter one time and the phrase the other. Unless you are using some custom code that queries db by itself, bypassing the model. BTW, I don't understand the purpose of posting the controller code.